# Help on distribution profile for iphone LITE version

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I just got my first app approved. Now I am creating my LITE version. DO I need to create a new Distribution profile or I just use the previous Distribution profile? Also do I need a new certificate for the LITE version. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a new certificate. If your app id for the full one contains. A wildcats character (*). Then you can use the same provisioning profile. If your app Id is unique, then you need a new app id and provisioning profile.